# to_json function in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use the new **to_json** function in Spark 2.1 to convert a Map type column to JSON. Code snippet below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_json

    val df = spark.sql("SELECT *, to_json(Properties) AS Prop, to_json(Measures) AS Meas FROM tempTable")
```

However, I get the below error. Any ideas what could be wrong?

```
    org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'to_json'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 10
```

Comment: What's the schema of `tempTable`? Why don't you use Dataset API and `to_json` directly (but rather use `spark.sql`)?

Comment: The types of columns being converted are Map<String,String>. Will try the Dataset API.

Comment: `to_json` works with dataframe/datasets. You're trying to execute it in SQL/Hive.